# "Extend" option works within Blender, but when model exported to FBX, the texture repeats instead of being extended

Tags: materials

The "Extend" option in Material->Surface works within Blender, but when the model is exported to FBX, the texture repeats instead of being the edge pixels being repeated. Any ideas?